Expression of a stochastic process at a stopping time: $X_{\tau}$
Let $(X_t)_{t \in [0,\infty)}$ be a real valued stochastic process, let $\mathcal{F}$ be a filtration on $[0,\infty)$. Let $\tau$ be a stopping time of $\mathcal{F}$. Is it possible to give an expression of $X_\tau$ in general (or under suitable conditions on $\tau$)?
If the index set is discrete, i.e., if we consider $(X_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$, then $X_\tau = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}X_n \cdot\mathbb{I}_{ \{ \tau=n \} }$ because $\{\tau=n\}\in \mathcal{F}_n \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$.
But what about a process over continuous time?
My attempt
I tried to extend the expression in the discrete case to the continuous case. Let $(U_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be defined by $U_n=\mathbb{I}_{ \{ T \leq n \} } \; \forall n \geq 1$.
Also define $(Y_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ as $Y_n = \sum_{m=1}^{n}X_m \cdot\mathbb{I}_{ \{ \tau=m \} } = \sum_{m=1}^{n}X_m \cdot\big( \mathbb{I}_{ \{ \tau \leq m \} } - \mathbb{I}_{ \{ \tau \leq m-1 \} } \big) = \sum_{m=1}^{n}X_m \cdot\big( U_m - U_{m-1} \big) = \int_{0}^{m} X \, dU$
and consequently $Y_{\tau} = \int_{0}^{\tau} X \, dU$.
Then I would be drawn to claim that the same expression also holds for a stochastic process over continuous time, such as $(X_t)_{t \in [0,\infty) }$.
But I do not know if this is correct nor if there is a more clear expression in the case of continuous time. Any help would be appreciated.

Is there a reason you prefer to write it as some sort of integral instead of just $X_{\tau}$?  I'm not seeing why one would want a different expression for it than $X_\tau$.

No, I would just like to better know what $X_{\tau}$ looks like. Writing it as an integral was just the only attempt I could come up with. The expression in the discrete case helped me to clarify what $X_{\tau}$ is and solve exercises. Since one cannot sum uncountably many terms, I tried to use the integral expression to extend it to continuous time, hoping it would give me some insights.

For simplicity I'm going to assume that $\tau(\omega)<\infty$ for each $\omega$.
Then $X_\tau(\omega) = \phi\circ\psi(\omega)$, where $\psi$ maps $\omega$ to $(\omega,\tau(\omega))$ and $\phi(\omega,t)=X_t(\omega)$. Thinking of $X_\tau$ as a composition of maps in this way, you can check that if $X$ is progressively measurable, then $X_\tau$ is $\mathcal F_\tau$-measurable.
If the sample paths $t\mapsto X_t(\omega)$ are right continuous, then you have
$$
X_\tau(\omega) =\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^\infty X_{(k+1)/n}(\omega)\cdot 1_{[k/n,(k+1)/n)}(\tau(\omega)),
$$
the limiting case of your discrete expression. An analogous limit holds if $t\mapsto X_t(\omega)$ is left continuous.
